# Centered vertical line causing width is issues

Tags: html, css

I have been able to create a centered vertical line but it increases my webpage width off of my screen! I would like some insight on how I can create a centered vertical line down my page while keeping page width to fit my screen (so that there is no horizontal scroll bar).

When I have removed the line my page width is perfect therefore I do not think it is one of my divs causing the problem.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue
}

.vertical_line {
  border-left: 6px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}

.section-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.section-3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50;
  width: 500px;
  height: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-2">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a style="background-color:grey; width:100px">this is my nav bar</a>
  </div>
  <div class="vertical_line"></div>
</section>

<section class="section-3">
  <div class="paragraph"></div>
</section>

<div class="vertical_line"></div>
```

Comment: Can I ask, why not use `flex` or `grid` or something similar? or what is this for?

Comment: I am very new and do not know much...I will research that though.

Answer (score 1):

Problem arises because you used `position: relative;` and shifted it 50% left, but it means element is still part of flow and shifting it pushes it  past the edge of the screen. On the other hand position absolute removes it from the flow. But if you want to use `position: relative;` for some reason, then add `overflow-x : hidden;` in the body, it will work fine in your case. Also a good CSS reset always helps, so as you do not get unexpected scrollbars.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.vertical_line {
  border-left: 6px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}

.section-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.section-3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50;
  width: 500px;
  height: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>

<section class="section-2">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a style="background-color:grey; width:100px">this is my nav bar</a>
  </div>

  <div class="vertical_line"></div>

</section>


<section class="section-3">
  <div class="paragraph"></div>
</section>

<div class="vertical_line"></div>

</html>
```

With help of `overflow-x: hidden;` and `position : relative;` :

```css
 * {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;

 }

 body {
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 100vh;
   overflow-x: hidden;
 }

 .vl {
   border-left: 6px solid black;
   height: 5000px;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
 }
```

```html
  <html>

    <body>
      <h2>Vertical Line</h2>
      <div class="vl"></div>
    </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: the css reset has made a big space between my header and nav bar. Do you know why?

Comment: @Seth If i can see the code,  maybe i can

Comment: @Seth It may be due to your margin collapse getting fixed, which can be either due to either position: absolute , or margin getting 0 for some elements. Not a bad thing, just check what's causing the space, and fix it accordingly, most probably some padding or margin which was not visible before.

Comment: Thanks so much @SuryanshSingh I will try sort it out